# Where is the New button in the Receiving Addresses windows of bitcoin core 0.17.0?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm not imaging this right - the New button in Receiving Addresses of bitcore core has just disappeared in 0.17.0?

Answer (score 4):

Press "request payment" to get an address.

The button on the address book was redundant and was removed by [PR12721](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/12721).